# How to find the isomorphism between two graphs while the other is not

Tags: graph-theory

> How to find the isomorphism between two graphs while the other is not

[image]

It seems very difficult for me to find out the isomorphism because I cannot even determine which two of them are isomorphic

Comment: Please make your question self-contained.

Comment: In general [finding isomorphisms is not an easy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_isomorphism_problem). You need a systematic approach; if you have not been given any process then hopefully this will encourage you to find something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT

Each graph has $6$ vertices with a degree of $3$ and $3$ vertices with a degree of $4$. So, since there are fewer of the latter, start by focusing on the three vertices with degree $4$, see how they are related to each other, and go from there.